# "if at all" repeats main-clause subject and verb?

Tags: conditional-constructions, ellipsis

Is "if at all" of the following understood as "(even) if the new law helps new immigrants at all"?

> The new law will fail to help new immigrants significantly, **if at all**.

I'd appreciate your help.

Answer (score 4):

What is ellipted in that concession is "if [the new law...helps them] at all".

With **fails** it is a little "off". But the polarity is

> The new law will not help immigrants significantly, if it helps them at all.

Stylistically it would be clearer to write it that way, or like this:

> The new law will offer immigrants little, if any, help.

Comment: What does 'concession' mean here? I didn't find a good definition for this use.

Comment: @dan What I meant was that **if it helps them at all** *concedes* the possibility that the new law may not help them in any way whatsoever.  **concession** is the noun form of the (Latin origin) verb **concede**, just as **procession** is the noun form of **proceed**, **recession** of **recede**, etc.

Comment: I don't feel like I understand "concedes the possibility" either. :(

Comment: @dan: Perhaps different punctuation will help you. *He won't understand much of what you said—if he understands any of it.*    The *if*-clause there accepts the possibility that *nothing* of what you said will make sense to him.  The *if*-clause is NOT a conditional there as  it is in *She will be angry if you forget to pick her up at the station.*

Answer (score 1):

You are correct. The sentence means that the new law won't be able to help new immigrants a lot. Maybe it won't help them at all